# how Create buttons during runtime?

Tags: android

I am developing an android attendance system in which the user enters the total number(int) of students in a class in Main_Activity and that many numbers of buttons are created in 2nd activity. How can I use the user input to create a list of buttons (used to mark present or absent) during runtime.

**Code to save Int value**

```
EditText total_roll_Name   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.roll_total_input);
String total_roll_text = total_roll_Name.getText().toString();

i.putExtra("totalRoll", total_roll_text);
```

Comment: use RecyclerView instead.

Answer (score 1):

Create button run time by below code and add into linear layout

```
Button dButton= new Button(this);
             myButton.setText("Add Me");

             LinearLayout lay= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
             LayoutParams layPar= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
             lay.addView(dButton, layPar);
```

Comment: will the app be stable if it loop the code using 100 or more times ?

Comment: There is nothing different between add view at run time or not .App will be stable

Answer (score 0):

i think you need attendance module right?.you have all student roll no in database.if you have then get a data from database in custom listview with checkbox and you can easily mark or unmark present or not.i already developed this type of system.if you need then i send you.

Comment: It will be very helpful If you send the link to it.

Comment: but first you explain which type of module you needed.so i send separate module

Comment: you see in all app in attendance management system having listview with checkbox you can check for attended student.you need exactly this type of module?

Comment: no one with check box will do

Comment: means? which type of system.you have reference app then send link.